# Insertar imegenes obtenidas de una pi externa en un cpt de worpress

Tags: php, api, wordpress

cree una integración con crm a traves de su api para guardar la informacion de los inmuebles en custom post types en wordpress y poder mostrar estos en el frontend, este custom post type tiene campos personalizados creados con advanced custom fields, uno de los campos que cree es de galeria en la cual quiero guardar las fotos del inmueble, el problema es que las fotos que me vienen en formato url a traves de la api del crm, no se guardan en el campo de galeria de acf pro, todo lo demás se guarda bien pero las imágenes no, la api me entrega una array con las url de las imágenes.

A continuación les muestro mi codigo:

```
//Permitimos que la funcion se pueda activar mediante ajax
add_action(
  'wp_ajax_nopriv_get_properties_from_api',
  'get_properties_from_api'
);
add_action(
  'wp_ajax_get_properties_from_api',
  'get_properties_from_api'
);

function get_properties_from_api(){
  if ( current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) ) {
    $current_page = ( ! empty( $_POST['current_page'] ) ) 
      ? $_POST['current_page'] : 1;

    $properties = [];

    //Clave de autorizacion de la api
    $args = array(
      'headers' => array(
        'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
        'Authorization' => 'Bearer 56c24c3c83f44b4ca3bc7e7a1c807177'
      )
    );

    //Recogiendo datos de la api
    $results = wp_remote_retrieve_body( wp_remote_get(
      'https://witei.com/api/v1/houses/?page=' . $current_page . '&per_page=1',
      $args
    ));

    // Convertimos los resultados en una matriz de PHP
    $results = json_decode( $results );
    $properties[] = $results->results;

    // Recorremos el array de propiedades
    foreach($properties[0] as $property){

      // Creamos variables para Titulo, slug y direccion
      $property_title = $property->kind . ' - ' .
         $property->street . ' - ' . $property->town;
      $property_title = ucwords($property_title);
      $property_slug = sanitize_title(
        $property->kind . ' en ' . $property->street . ', ' . $property->town
      );
      $property_direction = $property->street . ' ' .
        $property->street_number . ', ' . $property->zip_code .
        ', ' . $property->town . ', ' . $property->province;

      // Comprobaremos si la propiedad se va a vender o rentar
      $precio;
      $property_renting = $property->renting;
      $property_selling = $property->selling;

      if(!$property_renting && $property_selling){

        $property_operation = 'Venta';
        $precio = number_format( $property->selling_cost, 0, ".", "." );
      } else {

        $property_operation = 'Alquiler';
        $precio = number_format( $property->renting_cost, 0, ".", "." );
      }

      // Comprobaremos si la propiedad ya existe
      $existing_property = get_page_by_path(
        $property_slug, 'OBJECT', 'propiedades'
      );

      if($existing_property === null){
        // Insertaremos el post en la base de datos
        $inserted_property = wp_insert_post([
          'post_name' => $property_slug,
          'post_title' => $property_title,
          'post_type' => 'propiedades',
          'meta_input' => array(
            'identificacion' => $property->identifier,
            'descripcion' => $property->description,
            'direccion' => $property_direction,
            'provincia' => $property->province,
            'codigo-postal' => $property->zip_code,
            'ciudad' => $property->town,
            'calle' => $property->street,
            'numero-de-calle' => $property->street_number,
            'tipo-de-propiedad' => $property->kind,
            'plantas' => $property->floor,
            'dormitorios' => $property->bedrooms,
            'banos' => $property->bathrooms,
            'superficie' => $property->area,
            'superficie-parcela' => $property->area_plot,
            'superficie-util' => $property->area_util,
            'ano-de-construccion' => $property->year_built,
            'tipo-de-operacion' => $property_operation,
            'precio' => $precio,
            'periodicidad-de-cobro' => $property->renting_period,
            'fotos' => $fotos,
            'email_de_propietario' => $property->owner->email,
            'fecha-de-actualizacion' => $property->updated
          ),
          'post_status' => 'publish'
        ]);

        if(
          is_wp_error( $inserted_property )
          || $inserted_property === 0
        ) {
          error_log("Error: ". $inserted_property->get_error_message());
          return false;
        }
      } else {
        $existing_property_id = $existing_property->ID;
        $exisiting_property_timestamp = get_post_meta(
          $existing_property_id, 'fecha-de-actualizacion', true
        );

        if( $property->updated > $exisiting_property_timestamp ){

          $inserted_property = wp_insert_post([
            'ID' => $existing_property_id,
            'post_name' => $property_slug,
            'post_title' => $property_title,
            'post_type' => 'propiedades',
            'meta_input'   => array(
              'identificacion' => $property->identifier,
              'descripcion' => $property->description,
              'direccion' => $property_direction,
              'provincia' => $property->province,
              'codigo-postal' => $property->zip_code,
              'ciudad' => $property->town,
              'calle' => $property->street,
              'numero-de-calle' => $property->street_number,
              'tipo-de-propiedad' => $property->kind,
              'plantas' => $property->floor,
              'dormitorios' => $property->bedrooms,
              'banos' => $property->bathrooms,
              'superficie' => $property->area,
              'superficie-parcela' => $property->area_plot,
              'superficie-util' => $property->area_util,
              'ano-de-construccion' => $property->year_built,
              'tipo-de-operacion' => $property_operation,
              'precio-venta' => $property->selling_cost,
              'precio-alquiler' => $property->renting_cost,
              'periodicidad-de-cobro' => $property->renting_period,
              'fotos' => $property->pictures,
              'fecha-de-actualizacion' => $property->updated
            ),
            'post_status' => 'publish'
          ]);
        }
      }
    }

    // Esto nos permite llamar a la funcion mediante ajax
    $current_page = $current_page + 1;
    wp_remote_post( admin_url(
      'admin-ajax.php?action=get_properties_from_api'),
      [
        'blocking' => false,
// Esto nos permite activar la funcion y
// dejarnos ir a otra pagina sin bloquearnos
        'sslverify' => false, // Desactiva la verificacion del SSl.
        'body' => [
          'current_page' => $current_page
        ]
      ]
    );
  } else {
    echo "No eres administrador";
  }
}
```

Comment: Deberás crear la imagen desde la URL y guardarla en tu servidor. [Revisa las respuestas a esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10233577/5587982).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrias usar la función `media_sideload_image()` para subir las imagenes a tu servidor, luego retornas un ID y llenas un array con los ID's de las imagenes para de ultimo actualizar tu field pasandole ese array con imágenes.

```
// Obtenemos el ID del Post
// Agrega el ID Real de tu post

$post_id = 99;

// Encolamos los archivos necesarios para subir la imagen

require_once (ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/media.php' );
require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php' );
require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php' );

// Creamos un array con todas nuestras urls

$images = array(
  'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2022/10/16/13/53/early-morning-7525151_960_720.jpg',
  'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/12/01/20/28/road-1072823_960_720.jpg',
  'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/23/22/00/tree-736885_960_720.jpg'
);

// Creamos un array vacio
$images_ids = array();

// Verificamos si hay imagenes
if ( $images ) :
  // Si hay imagenes las recorremos una a una
  foreach ( $images as $url ) {

    // Subimos la imagen a nuestro servidor, le pasamos la url y retornamos el ID
    $image = media_sideload_image( $url, 0, null, 'id' );

    // Si no hay error llenamos nuestro array de ID's
    if ( !is_wp_error( $image ) ) :
      array_push( $images_ids, $image );
    endif;

  }
endif;

// Verificamos que el array de ID tenga datos
if ( $images_id ) :

  // Actualizamos nuestro field
  // Usaremos la Key de nuestro field
  // Le pasamos nuestro array con los ID's de las imagenes
  // Le pasamos el ID del post
  update_field( 'field_0000000000', $images_ids , $post_id );

endif;
```

No he probado esto, pero debería funcionar con sus respectivas modificaciones.

Comment: Esto se ve interesante, ahora podria en vez de relacionarlas con el post utilizar el array con los ids para rellenar el campo 'fotos' al momento de subir el post del inmueble?

Comment: Logre hacerlo como te dije, cuando ya tengo rellenado el array con los ids de las imagenes se lo paso al campo de fotos, muchas gracias por tu comentario fuiste gran ayuda, llevaba dias dando le vueltas a esto sin encontrar solucion

Comment: Oye una consulta, en el codigo cuando ve que un inmueble ya existe pero le cambiaron informacion este se actualiza, ahora con las imagenes como se haria para evitar subir imagenes repetidas y solo las nuevas?

Comment: Tendrás que verificar que las urls o nombre de las imagenes coincidan con las de tu post, si no subes las nuevas imagenes y actualizas el array. Puedes obtener el ID de las imagenes para obtener la información meta, aunque lo mejor es comparar el nombre de la imagen, tipo IMG-65.jpg, si es igual al de tu array entonces la omites. Esa sería la solución que se me ocurre.

Comment: Si algo así estaba pensando, misma lógica para determinar si un inmueble existe o no a través de comparar el titulo, gracias nuevamente por responder.

Answer (score 0):

estoy haciendo una integración parecida pero en este caso solo quiero subir una imagen a wordpress, pero en este caso no me deja hacerlo, la funciona de media_sideload_image me dice que la url no es valida.

```
                        // Encolamos los archivos necesarios para subir la imagen
                        require_once (ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/media.php' );
                        require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php' );
                        require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php' );
        
                        $url = $gallery[0]['url'];

                        // Subimos la imagen a nuestro servidor, le pasamos la url y retornamos el ID
                        $image_thumbnail = media_sideload_image( '$url' );
```

Comment: Esto no es una respuesta, por favor lee [answer], conforme a tu pregunta, revisa que la url sea correcta y remueve las comillas de ( '$url' )

Comment: Quite la comillas y al hacer var dump me sale esto: object(WP_Error)#25808 (3) { ["errors"]=> array(1) { ["image_sideload_failed"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(27) "URL de la imagen no válida" } } ["error_data"]=> array(0) { } ["additional_data":protected]=> array(0) { } }

Comment: Esta es la url que estoy mandando: https://image.wasi.co/eyJidWNrZXQiOiJzdGF0aWN3Iiwia2V5IjoiaW5tdWVibGVzXC9nMTEwMTgyMzIwMjMxMTI3MDkzNzE3LmpwZyIsImVkaXRzIjp7Im5vcm1hbGlzZSI6dHJ1ZSwicm90YXRlIjowLCJyZXNpemUiOnsid2lkdGgiOjU1NSwiaGVpZ2h0Ijo0MTYsImZpdCI6ImNvbnRhaW4iLCJiYWNrZ3JvdW5kIjp7InIiOjI1NSwiZyI6MjU1LCJiIjoyNTUsImFscGhhIjoxfX19fQ==